# iOS App won't start after OTA deployment of the same version

Tags: iphone, ios, deployment, over-the-air

We're distributing an iOS App over the air to our beta-testers. We've now noticed, that if a tester installs the exact same build of the app he already has on the system, the app won't start anymore. There are no provisioning warnings or anything like that. The screen just goes black for about 1/4 of a second and the app quits again. If we delete the app, the install will work fine after that. Also upgrading the app to a new build works fine. This only happens if we try to install the exact same build. Has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 1):

A reason of crash of a new version of the app is that the serialisation of objects in cache has changed. If it's the case, you may clean the cache at the first launch. 
Another reason may be an old expired profile.

Comment: Hi Malinois, thanks for your answer. Both solutions did not work for us, and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. It turns out that the issue was related to the naming of the Bundle ID and Product Name. The bundle ID suffix should match the product name exactly without spaces or special characters. Many people (including myself) have changed the product name to reflect the name that they wish to be shown on the iPad home screen. It turns out that this should not be done, and the proper method is to match the Product Name to the Bundle ID suffix, and then in the Info.plist, there is a property called "Bundle Display Name" that can be changed to reflect what will be shown on the iPad's app home screen. Once I made this change, the error went away in all of my apps.

#### For example:

**Bundle ID:**
com.company.AppName
**Suffix:**
AppName
**Product Name (Build Settings):**
AppName
**Bundle Display Name (Info.plist):**
App Name (this can be whatever you wish)

Comment: The Problem has gone away in our app, we're not sure why, but thanks for your answer. +1